# Default values in domain object

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

How can I fill all fields on my domain object default values? Just use Moq or other library?

Comment: Is this for testing purposes?

Comment: Yes, i want test my domain logic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find [AutoFixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/) useful for that.